# When are rows in catalog_product_super_link not revomed with product removals?

Tags: ee-1.12, database

I found a strange behavior in the way Magento (EE 1.12) housekeeps the `catalog_product_super_link` table. When an associated simple product is deleted without being disassociated first, the entry corresponding to this link remains. Furthermore, when the disassociated configurable product is re-saved, the orphaned rows remain.

To replicate this, please try

1. Create a test configurable product and simple product
2. Associate the two.
3. Delete the simple product without disassociating.
4. Check the DB table with the following query.

   ```
   select l.*, p.sku
   from catalog_product_super_link as l
       left join catalog_product_entity as p
           on l.product_id = p.entity_id
   where l.parent_id = 1936;
   ```

And you'll get something like below where the `NULL` entries are former associations.

1769    1937    1936    NULL

1770    1938    1936    NULL

1771    1939    1936    NULL

1772    1940    1936    NULL

1773    1941    1936    bag-001

1776    1950    1936    bag-002

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure this is standard behavior?
I took a look at the table structure and it has 2 constaints on it.

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link` (                                                                                                                                        
    `link_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Link ID',                                                                                                            
    `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product ID',                                                                                                         
    `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Parent ID',                                                                                                           
    PRIMARY KEY (`link_id`),                                                                                                                                                         
    UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID_PARENT_ID` (`product_id`,`parent_id`),                                                                                     
    KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PARENT_ID` (`parent_id`),                                                                                                                    
    KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`),                                                                                                                  
    CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PARENT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
    CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE     
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This means that if a product is deleted (so the row is removed from `catalog_product_entity`) any row in the `catalog_product_super_link` that has that product id in the columns `parent_id` or `entity_id` will be deleted.

Check if you didn't lose the constraints on a database migration.

Comment: You're right about the constraints. I no longer have access to that database in question, but I wouldn't be surprised if constraints were removed.